# Is there an alias to refer to the last referenced file in the terminal?

Tags: bash, zsh

Currently, I'm running 2 commands in order like so:

```sh
nano ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

is there a shortcut like `!!` to reference the last referenced file? So that the terminal gets `source ~/.zshrc` without me retyping the path of the last file?

Comment: Is this question actually about bash? Given that you are explicitly referencing `.zshrc` files, I'm skeptical.

Comment: It's possible to put the filename in a variable but I'm not sure that such solution will be suitable in your case.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, seeing as they share many similarities, I figured the answer would be common to both shells.

Comment: @ThinkDigital Don't assume that. Somethings are *very* different. Take indirect parameter expansion. Give `foo=3; bar=foo`, `bash` lets you write `echo ${!bar}` to output 3; the `zsh` equivalent is `echo ${(P)bar}`.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask the reason for the down votes?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. Weird how that happens.

It's called a "bang history command". According to
[Bash history reuse and bang commands](http://www.softpanorama.org/Scripting/Shellorama/Bash_as_command_interpreter/bash_command_history_reuse.shtml#Using_selected_capabilities_of_bang_command)

> What is more important and convenient is that you can extract
> arguments from previous commands  (see below).
>
> For example: !!:1
> designates the first argument of the last command.  This can be
> shortened to !1.
>
> !!:$ designates the last argument of the preceding
> command. This may be shortened to !$.

Comment: For interactive usage, I prefer Meta-`.` (usually Alt-`.`) – lets me cycle through the last word of all previous commands.